# Aborted fetch is still calling "then" function?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, abort

I have a react component which calling fetch/abort on mount/unmount,
when I tried to move the fetch function to a separated class the "then" function is keep calling even after aborting the fetch request so the "Not Aborted" text is printed to the console.

It looks like this:

ReactComponent

```
class ReactComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.TodoService = new TodoService();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.TodoService.fetch().then(res => {
        console.log("Not Aborted");
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.TodoService.abort();
  }
}
```

TodoService

```
class TodoService {
  constructor() {
    this.controller = new AbortController();
    this.signal = this.controller.signal;
  }

  handleErrors(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response;
    }
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }

  fetch() {
    return fetch(`todos`, {
      signal: this.signal
    })
      .then(this.handleErrors)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  abort() {
    this.controller.abort();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it do it if you comment out your `catch()`. You return undefined in that catch which will also resolve the promise.

Comment: Yes! thank you @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it could come down to the `this` context.

try adding these to the *TodoService* **constructor**:

`this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this);
this.abort = this.abort.bind(this);`

You are calling those methods from a different context and the current contexts `this` will be used.

Here is the browser support for the [`AbortController`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=abortcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
fetch() {

     return fetch(`todos`, 
        {signal: this.signal}, 
        this.controller.abort()
   )
  .then(this.handleErrors)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```